# Calling modals through route

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

Can someone tell me which script is called here, I don't know why I can't call the same modal through route.
index.blade.php

```
@section('action-btn')
    <div class="float-end">
        <a href="#" data-size="lg" data-url="{{ route('roles.create') }}" data-ajax-popup="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="{{__('Create New Role')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="ti ti-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
@endsection
```

if it is called to me through the controller then modal create

```
public function create()
    {
        if(\Auth::user()->can('create role'))
        {
            $user = \Auth::user();
            if($user->type == 'super admin')
            {
                $permissions = Permission::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
            }
            else
            {
                $permissions = new Collection();
                foreach($user->roles as $role)
                {
                    $permissions = $permissions->merge($role->permissions);
                }
                $permissions = $permissions->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
            }

            return view('role.create', ['permissions' => $permissions]);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Permission denied.');
        }
    }
```

I can't understand which script I need to call the route like this through data-url="{{ route('roles.create') }}".

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -2):

You should also provide your web.php information so i can check it .
but you can also do it after checking the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers
Thank you.